# how is this differentiation possible?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A particle moves in the plane xy with constant acceleration a directed along the negative y–axis. The equation of motion of the particle has the form (where p and q are constants)
$$y = px –{qx}^2$$
in my book they differentiated both sides with respect to time and solved it as
$$\frac {dy}{dt}=p\frac{dx}{dt}+q\cdot 2x \cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$$
they later took $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as velocity in x-axis and solved it....
my question is that we dont know the relation of x with t.so how could we do $\frac{d}{dt}{qx}^2$ and get $q\cdot 2x\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$ after differentiating?
i have tried asking the question before and my ques got closed as i didnt know mathjax.so plz dont downvote and tell me what i can do to better edit the question.

Comment: so i can also provide full question but that would be irrelevant to my doubt and wont  provide new information.however,if you want i can type the complete question

Comment: First it should be known if p,x,q are functions of t. If this is the case, then you should use the multivariable chain rule. Good job on a [good](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) first question!

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash thanks.so as the question is a distance time graph so x is related to T, it is not mentioned how(like f(x)=2x).p and q are constants(i edited later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d\left(qx^2\right)}{dt}=\frac{d\left(qx^2\right)}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} \, .
$$
So
$$
\frac{d\left(qx^2\right)}{dt}=2qx\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}\, . \tag{*}\label{*}
$$
It is true that we don't know how $x$ is related to $t$, which is why it is not possible to simplify the expression $\frac{dx}{dt}$ any further. But regardless of how $x$ is related to $t$, the equation $\eqref{*}$ holds.

Comment: oh god how could i be so dumb to not think of that.Thanks its been 2 days since i have been searching the internet to get to the answer

Comment: @Karan: I'm glad I could help. This technique is known as *implicit differentiation* if you want to look into it more deeply.

Comment: @Karan: Yes, it's very unfortunate that the school curriculum is built around memorisation rather than understanding. Thankfully, if you are interested in studying mathematics at a higher level, then you won't have this problem.